# Ray tracer shadows lighter shadows at the base and weird shadow shape

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, rendering, raytracing

This is the code for shadows, though I have all my code in my repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/MrCappuccino/Tracey) for easier reading, [this is the main code for the shadows](https://github.com/MrCappuccino/Tracey/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L90), this is the code for the [sphere-ray intersections](https://github.com/MrCappuccino/Tracey/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L90) and this is the code for the [plane-ray intersections](https://github.com/MrCappuccino/Tracey/blob/master/src/Plane.cpp#L19):

```
bool shadowed = false;
Color finalColor = closestObjectColor.Scalar(AMBIENTLIGHT); // Add ambient light to the calculation
for(const auto &lightSource : lightSources)
{
    Vector lightDir = (lightSource->position - intersectionRayPos).Normalize(); // Calculate the directional vector towards the lightSource
    FPType cosineAngle = closestObjectNormal.Dot(lightDir);
    finalColor = finalColor.Scalar(cosineAngle);

    if(cosineAngle > 0)
    {
        Ray shadowRay(intersectionRayPos, (lightSource->position - intersectionRayPos).Normalize()); // Cast a ray from the first intersection to the light

        std::vector<FPType> secondaryIntersections;
        for(const auto &sceneObject : sceneObjects)
        {
            secondaryIntersections.push_back(sceneObject->GetIntersection(shadowRay));
        }

        Vector distanceToLight = lightSource->position + (intersectionRayPos.Negative()).Normalize();
        FPType distanceToLightMagnitude = distanceToLight.Magnitude();

        for(const auto &secondaryIntersection : secondaryIntersections)
        {
            if(secondaryIntersection > TOLERANCE && secondaryIntersection <= distanceToLightMagnitude)
            {
                shadowed = true;
                finalColor = finalColor.Scalar(cosineAngle);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
return finalColor.Clip();
```

The problem is that my shadows are lighter at the base, or the start of the shadow, which is well illustrated in this picture, you can as well see the weird shape of the shadow, which I'm not sure is right or not to be honest:
[image]

The same effect can be observed here and can very obviously be seen on the shadow that is on the maroon sphere, behind the gray sphere:
[image]

Another bug occurs where the shadow from a sphere in front of another gets displaced in a bad manner (shadow on maroon sphere behind blue sphere):

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you're using the angle to the light source affect the colour of your shadow.  I would expect you just use the ambient colour of the object at primary intersection, without any angle-based scale.  As for the shadow shape, it almost looks like the shadow-ray intersection code is passing straight through the top hemisphere (i.e. only intersecting bottom hemispheres.  To test this, try choosing a point in your image that should be in shadow (but isn't), and attempt to intersect a shadow ray with your scene.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "ambient color of the object"?

Comment: The diffuse colour of the object lit by ambient light.

Comment: I have tried that, but there's still a ["gradient"](http://puu.sh/nsk3L/4b4e65fff7.png) of the shadow, it's not entirely in 1 color.

Comment: But that's because you are scaling it by the angle to your lights.  You need to add all your colours together, not progressively multiply.  So you take ambient, then calculate colour from light 1 (if visible) and add then together, then you keep adding in light 2, 3, and so on until you've done all your lights.

Comment: https://github.com/MrCappuccino/Tracey/blob/master/src/main.cpp?t=4#L145 I'm actually doing that, i'm not scaling by the angle, but i'm still getting a gradient.

Comment: That code makes no sense.  Before your lighting loop, you should compute a diffuse ambient colour for your object.  Then, inside the loop test for intersection between object and light.  If the path is clear, then compute a diffuse lighted material colour (plus any phong etc) in some other variable, then _add_ it to `finalColor`.  If shadowed, then do nothing for that light.  Don't forget to reset your `shadowed` variable inside the loop.  Just move the whole variable in there.  It's not needed outside.

Comment: When you say "compute" a diffuse ambient color, what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I give up.  Every day we continue this, and you still don't get it.  I think you need to go and read some basic literature on ray tracing.

Comment: Well you're giving very vague answers... Sorry for troubling you. Almost every article i've read on ray tracing does it like i do.

Comment: When you finally solve this, make sure you come back and read the comments I made, and you will see they are not vague at all.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way we use to calculate shadows is:

int hitCount = 0;
for (light in allLights) {
    Ray point2Light = ...
    object = GetObjectHit(point2Light);
    if(object == light)
        hitCount++;
}

float shadowDarkness = (float)hitCount / (float)allLights.count;

Comment: Also the reason I guess for the issue with shadow shape is to do with intersection code.